# Trouble with dividing a multiplies number by two

Tags: python

I've created a variable that adds two numbers together than another which multiplies that number by 2. After these two functions I try to then divide the result of these two functions by two. It will not work. Is it because I did not make the result of the previous function a global variable?

I've tried making it a global var but it doesn't work.

```
def add(num1,num2):
    return num1 + num2

def multiply():
    mult = add(1,2)*2
    print(mult)

def divide():
    start = multiply() /2
    print(start)

divide()
```

I expected the result 3 but instead it threw up an error message instead. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You don't return anything from your functions.

Comment: You are returning anything in multiply function . add `return mult` in multiply function.

Comment: Generally, you should share the error message instead of expecting people to guess what output you're getting

Answer (score 2):

Your `multiply()` doesn't return anything so when the `divide()` starts to work, it tries to divide `None` to `2` and raises an error. Here is a bit fixed code:

```
def add(num1,num2):
    return num1 + num2

def multiply():
    mult = add(1,2)*2
    return mult

def divide():
    start = multiply() /2
    return start

print(divide())
```

It will print:

> `3.0`

---

But here is deeper problem:

Your `multiply` and `divide` functions have no inputs so they are useless and multiply function and divide function. You can rewrite them as:

```
def add(num1,num2):
    return num1 + num2

def multiply(num1,num2):
    return num1 * num2

def divide(num1,num2):
    return num1 / num2

print(divide(add(1, 3), multiply(2, 5)))
```

> `0.4`

Comment: Please vote for this to be a duplicate.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback) thank you so much!